# Any of java type or classes is recognized by Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I installed ubuntu 12.04

then I install java and I set my environment variable as usually

but eclipse can't recognize any java variable type or any class

`java -version`

```
 java version "1.7.0_45"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
 Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

`bashrc`

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
 export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven
 export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${MAVEN_HOME}/bin
```

How can I fix this problem ?

### [image]

[image]

Comment: Does eclipse launch? What is under the `Java > Installed JREs` properties menu?

Comment: yes it launch , the installed jre has the same path as in the bashrc

Comment: What libraries are under the `Java Build Path` for your Java project?

Comment: @Danny I added it to my question

Comment: How about showing us something that demonstrates the problem. There is nothing showing the error at the moment.

Comment: I don't what is the problem but it working now

Answer (score 0):

Check eclipse settings there is a "installed JRE" preference:

[image: Eclipse setting]

(linux, juno)

Also, make sure you have a "JRE System Library" in your project classpath:

[image: buildpath]

Comment: I added it to my question